# In Chrome, string oversizes its table cell when it contains an &

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm showing a list of URLs (taken from database) inside a table td.
The td element width is fixed. And each URL is shown inside a li that is inside this td.

In Firefox and IE, doesn't matter the characters that the URL has. When the URL is longer than the div width, the browser cuts it and show it in the following line. This is the expected behaviour.

Chrome makes it, but not in every case. When the URL has a long string of chars joined by '&', it doesn't cut it, extending the div width. Example of this kind of URL:

```
http://www.test.com/cgi-bin/test/test/test.cgi?lang=e&extra=&year=2009&month=09&day=25&vol=13&no=39&gn=5959&header=1&part=0&df=1&nt=gn&acurrentpage=12&agree=1&newfile=1
```

What is the problem?

I'll try to put here some css code (there's a lot of it, I hope I write everything related with the problem), so you can have it in consideration:

```
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, select, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#contentInner {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #40545F;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 988px;
}
element.style {
    display: table;
}
.ventana table {
    color: #40545F;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 8px;
    width: 885px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.ventana td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E0E4EA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
p, li {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

My table is inside a div called "contentInner", which gets its width fixed.

And this is my HTML:

```
<div id="contentWrapper">       

            <table class="detectionTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">URLs found</th>
                    </tr>
                    <c:if test="${not empty URLs}">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col21">URLs</td>
                            <td class="col22">
                                <ul>
                                <li>http://test.eu/test/test.do?uri=OJL.PDF</li>
                                <li>http://www.test.com/cgi-bin/test/test/test.cgi?lang=e&extra=&year=2009&month=09&day=25&vol=13&no=39&gn=5959&header=1&part=0&df=1&nt=gn&acurrentpage=12&agree=1&newfile=1</li>
                                </ul>                                                               
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:if> 
            </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Give your html codes so that we can work this out

Comment: It’s not HTML code but something that is used to generate HTML code.

Comment: The only thing it makes is add a li with a string for each url in a list, so the final HTML is <ul><li>one_name</li><li>othername</li>...</ul>, but OK, I'll change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by different line breaking behavior in browsers. It’s a real mess, but it can be controlled [in different ways](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html). The simplest way is `word-wrap: break-word` as suggested by @yunzen. But it means that breaks are allowed anywhere.

For readability of URLs in text, breaks should take place only at certain points, such as after “&” (where modern versions of Firefox break by default). To achieve this, you need to insert tags or special characters that allow line breaks. This is somewhat complicated, but if you can ignore old IE versions like IE 6, using the ZERO-WIDTH SPACE character works well. (If IE 6 is relevant, you need a trick like `<wbr><a class="wbr"></a>` tag with the style sheet `.wbr:after { content: "\00200B"; }`, so it gets dirty.

Example, showing first the issue in a minimal case, then the simple “break anywhere” method, and finally the method of adding line breaking permissions:

```
<style>
div { border: solid; width: 25em;  }
</style>
<div>
http://www.test.com/cgi-bin/test/test/test.cgi?lang=e&amp;extra=&amp;year=2009&amp;month=09&amp;day=25&amp;vol=13&amp;no=39&amp;gn=5959&amp;header=1&amp;part=0&amp;df=1&amp;nt=gn&amp;acurrentpage=12&amp;agree=1&amp;newfile=1
</div>
<hr>
With word-wrap: break-word:
<div style="word-wrap: break-word;">
http://www.test.com/cgi-bin/test/test/test.cgi?lang=e&amp;extra=&amp;year=2009&amp;month=09&amp;day=25&amp;vol=13&amp;no=39&amp;gn=5959&amp;header=1&amp;part=0&amp;df=1&amp;nt=gn&amp;acurrentpage=12&amp;agree=1&amp;newfile=1
</div>
<hr>
With ZWSP:
<div>
http://www.test.com/cgi-bin/test/test/test.cgi?lang=e&amp;&#x200b;extra=&amp;&#x200b;year=2009&amp;&#x200b;month=09&amp;&#x200b;day=25&amp;&#x200b;vol=13&amp;&#x200b;no=39&amp;&#x200b;gn=5959&amp;&#x200b;header=1&amp;&#x200b;part=0&amp;&#x200b;df=1&amp;&#x200b;nt=gn&amp;&#x200b;acurrentpage=12&amp;&#x200b;agree=1&amp;&#x200b;newfile=1
</div>
```

(Using `&amp;` instead of plain `&` is the right thing to do even though it obscures the HTML source code. This is however just a matter of principle and does not affect the problem at hand.)

Comment: I have added a line to replace & by &amp;, the URL name is shown as it is in database, but the problem persists (chrome doesn't cut it). If I also add the ZERO_WIDTH SPACE then it works well, I hope noone uses IE6 :)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

in you CSS

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap

Comment: @Goyo, in my test on Chrome 24beta on Win 7, it works. If it does not work in your environment, please post a minimal test case and describe the environment in more detail.

Comment: I have updated Chrome to 24beta and the issue remains the same. I'm also on Win 7. With the htmlcode should be enough to test. If you remove the break-word, does it works for you also? If not, should I include any library or something else, so the browser could understand this word-wrap?

Comment: I'm testing it including this sentence at p,li element in CSS. Should I have to include it in any other CSS element?